# I'm getting the java.io.NotSerializableException regardless of Serializable interface implementation

Tags: java, serializable, notserializableexception

I'm getting a NotSerializableException when I run my code and I'm not sure why.

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: passOffs.StampedLevels
```

I've checked to make sure that the class implements the `Serializable` interface and all the fields within the class are `Serializable`.

Here is my class:

```
package passOffs;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class StampedLevels implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String levelItem;
    private String date;
    private boolean passed;

    public StampedLevels(String levelItem, String date, boolean passed) {
        this.levelItem = levelItem;
        this.date = date;
        this.passed = passed;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return levelItem;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        if(passed) {
            return "Passed";
        }
        else {
            return "Un-Passed";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getItem() + "    " + getStatus() + "   " + getDate();
    }
}
```

Also, here is the stack trace I am getting along with the error, in case that helps.

```
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue.readObject(CircularFifoQueue.java:141)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1160)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2216)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at passOffs.levelInfo.readObjectFromFile(levelInfo.java:1793)
    at passOffs.levelInfo.passOff(levelInfo.java:407)
    at passOffs.ChoirDisplay$9.actionPerformed(ChoirDisplay.java:362)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Edit: The StackTrace errors are likely happening around here

```
Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
Date newDate = dateTime.getTime();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
String date = df.format(newDate);

Queue<StampedLevels> tempQueue = (Queue<StampedLevels>) readObjectFromFile(queueSource);

tempQueue.add(new StampedLevels(item, date, true));

writeToFile(tempQueue, queueSource);
```

but the NotSerializable error is pointing elsewhere.

Here is my writeToFile method:

```
public void writeToFile(Object object, String source) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(source);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objectOut.writeObject(object);
            objectOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

readObjectFromFile method

```
private Object readObjectFromFile(String source) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(source);
            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            Object obj = objectIn.readObject();

            objectIn.close();
            return obj;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are your setter methods?

Comment: Can u add the code where this class is used

Comment: ```Queue<StampedLevels> tempQueue = (Queue<StampedLevels>) readObjectFromFile(queueSource);
   tempQueue.add(new StampedLevels(item, date, true));
   
   writeToFile(tempQueue, queueSource);```

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm explicitly initializing the Stamped Levels class from a different class so I only need getter methods. I'm trying to create a FIFO Queue of Stamped Levels.

Comment: Which implementation of the `Queue` interface is used in your program? Can you show the code where the `Queue<StampedLevels>` is created initially?

Comment: According to the stack trace you posted, line 1793 in file `levelInfo.java` is throwing the error. Please [edit] your question to include, at least, the code for method `readObjectFromFile()`. In fact, a [mcve] would be better.

Comment: Yea.  I suspect that the problem is that >>this<< version of the class is different to the version that was actually being serialized.  A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would resolve that.  I would also note that the error message and the stacktrace don't match.  The former is for writing, and the latter is for reading.

Comment: You are reading from a file dating from before you added `implements Serializable`. You will have to throw it away, as all it contains is this exception. You would also have got a `NotSerializableException` when *creating* this file.

Comment: Note that the top of your question and the stack trace do not agree.

Comment: Ok. I've found the problem. First, when I originally wrote the Queue to the file I initialized it like so: Queue<StampedLevels> tempQueue = new CircularFifoQueue<StampedLevels>(); so I was trying to cast a CircularFifoQueue to a Queue. Second, the original file was corrupt from the programs later edits so it wasn't helping anymore. I've overwritten the file with a new, empty CircularFifoQueue to the file and am now casting to CircularFifoQueue and the program works fine.

Comment: No. I told you the problem. The file wasn't 'corrupt from the program's later edits', it was invalid from the start: you got a `NotSerializabeException` when writing it, so you added `implements Serializable` but you then tried to de-serialize the original file, somehow expecting it to have magically fixed itself.

Comment: @user207421 I've looked a bit deeper into my situation and you're right, the file wasn't 'corrupt from the program's later edits' in fact the file was perfectly fine. I've found that the real problem was the file was fine the whole time containing only one object(the CircularFifoQueue<StampedLevels>) but I was trying to cast the object read in, to a Queue<StampedLevels> when it was a CircularFifoQueue. This caused a mismatch during the serialization process which threw the Exception. I was casting to the wrong object and trying to write that object back into the file.

Comment: The casting mistake was happening in one of the code segments **shown above** during the initialization of the queue.